# subprocess.Popen return stderr instead of stdout

Tags: python, git, subprocess

I am trying to send `git push` command with `subprocess.Popen`. Command is successful but the git command output is returned by `subprocess` under `stderr` instead off `stdout`

```
def execute_cmds(commands):

    for cmd in commands:
        send_commands = subprocess.Popen(
            cmd,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            universal_newlines=True,
            shell=True
            )
    send_commands.wait()
    output, errors = send_commands.communicate()

    print('OUTPUT: {}'.format(output))
    print('ERRORS: {}'.format(errors))
```

```
OUTPUT:
ERRORS: warning: redirecting to https://gitlab.com/networkAutomation/git_test_module.git/
To https://gitlab.com/networkAutomation/git_test_module
   afb2400..fbcb4db  HEAD -> master
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for Git: Git prints its output to its standard error stream.

Comment: I believe is not true. Because the output for git commit goes under stdout

```ERRORS:
OUTPUT: [master 426aad3] My amazing backup
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 test.txt```

Comment: It's normal for the command you're using (`git push` or something that invokes it). It's normal for `git fetch` as well. Some Git commands print some output to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the stderr to the standard output:

```
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
```

so you can get the value returned in stdout